# Error in SOAP response when called to java web service

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I've a Java web service that return a list of documents stored in a Alfresco CMS.

This web services normally run correctly and when I call it the responses are OK. But sometimes this is not so and the following error occurs in the SOAP response:

```
2014-10-24 12:58:17,047 ERROR [com.company.ws.Exceptions.HrwsException] : WSDoAllSender: cannot get SOAP envlope from messageorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=1: Attribute "actor" bound to namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" was already specified for element "ns7:QueryHeader".
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.generalException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: WSDoAllSender: cannot get SOAP envlope from messageorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=1: Attribute "actor" bound to namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" was already specified for element "ns7:QueryHeader".
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:WSDoAllSender: cannot get SOAP envlope from messageorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=1: Attribute "actor" bound to namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" was already specified for element "ns7:QueryHeader".
    at org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender.invoke(WSDoAllSender.java:161)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.query(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:753)

...

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:

WSDoAllSender: cannot get SOAP envlope from messageorg.xml.sax.SAXException: Fatal Error: URI=null Line=1: Attribute "actor" bound to namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" was already specified for element "ns7:QueryHeader".
    at org.apache.ws.axis.security.WSDoAllSender.invoke(WSDoAllSender.java:161)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:127)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at org.alfresco.webservice.repository.RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.query(RepositoryServiceSoapBindingStub.java:753)
```

This is my SOAP request sending from Client:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sch="http://<hostname>/webServices/schema">
  <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
     <sch:listDocumentsRequest username="*****" password="*****">
     <sch:tipo>F</sch:tipo>
     <sch:cod>1</sch:cod>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <sch:abono>0</sch:abono>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <sch:codDivision>01</sch:codDivision>
  </sch:listDocumentsRequestt>
```

Any idea? What's happened?
Thanks

**UPDATED:**

I attached wsdl:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://hostname/webServices/definitions">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://hostname/webServices/schema" version="2.2">
        <xsd:element name="listDocumentsRequest">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="tipo" type="docType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="cod" type="codType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="abono" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="codDivision" type="codDivisionType"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attributeGroup ref="identificacion"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element><!-- listarDocumentosResponse -->
        <xsd:element name="listarDocumentosResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" ref="listarDocumentosResponseItem"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="excepcion" type="wsException"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="fechaConsulta" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="listarDocumentosResponseItem">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="documentoID" type="UUID"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="rutaHttp" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="abono" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" name="prov" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="codDivision" type="codDivisionType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="num" type="numType"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="fecha" type="xsd:date"/>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="cos" type="cosType"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="codDivisa" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:elment>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="listDocumentsRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="sch:listDocumentsRequest" name="listDocumentsRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="listarDocumentosResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="sch:listarDocumentosResponse" name="listarDocumentosResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="GestorDocumWs">
    <wsdl:operation name="listarDocumentos">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:listDocumentsRequest" name="listDocumentsRequest"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:listarDocumentosResponse" name="listarDocumentosResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="GestorDocumWsSoap11" type="tns:GestorDocumWs">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="listarDocumentos">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input name="listDocumentsRequest">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="listarDocumentosResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="miServicio">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:GestorDocumWsSoap11" name="GestorDocumWsSoap11">
        <soap:address location="http://hostname/webServices/miServicio/snap"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Comment: can you share your WSDL file? It will help to identify problem

Comment: Can you show the XSD file where ``ns7:QueryHeader`` is defined?

Comment: I updated the case with wsdl file